# Regexp to grab protocol from URL

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a variable called URL and it's assigned a value of `http://www.google.com`. I can also received the URL via ftp, hence it'll be `ftp://ftp.google.com`. How can I have it so I grab everything before the `:`? I'll have an if/else condition afterwards to test the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^[^:]+/
```

If you want to prevent 'www.foobar.com' (which has no protocol specified) to match as protocol:

```
/^[^:]+(?=:\/\/)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it is url

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#()?&//=]*)
```

check before it is url and after get ...

protocol

```
^(http[s]?://)
```

port

```
\:[0-9]{2,}
```

domain

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
/^(.*?):/
```