# Determine protocol of the link using Python alternatives

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need to find out the best way to determine what protocol is used to access a particular link. The input: string link address (starting with `protocol://...`)

This is what I find the most convenient way to implement the necessary functionality:

```
def detectProtocol(url):
    ind = url.find("://")
    return url[0:ind] if (ind != -1) else 'default_prot'
```

Yet I'm interested what is the best way from the performance point of view. Maybe using `re` matching would be better? (but not that user friendly)

Thanks in advance!

P.S. If you have your very own alternatives you are welcome to share them

Comment: Rather than trying to invent your own URL parsing scheme, why not use Python's standard library? Depending on which version of Python you're using, you'll want either the `urllib.parse` module (Python 3) or the `urlparse` module (Python 2).

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for an aswer. Actually I have to use something working both with 2.7.x and 3.x python versions. I'll take a look at what you propose. UPDATE: using a built-ins is a good choice but the problem that I didn't find a way to use it in both python majors ;(

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883871/regexp-to-grab-protocol-from-url

Comment: @MichaelHoff it's about comparison not about the actual way to use regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Performance comparison

This comparison ignores stability of the functions used and other aspects like synergetic effects. `urlparse` for example provides more information than only the scheme and could hence be used to provide data for other needs.

#### Python 2.7.11+

```
Testing detect_protocol_by_index
1.56482505798
Testing detect_protocol_by_urlparse
9.13317012787
Testing detect_protocol_by_regex
3.11044311523
```

#### Python 3.5.1+

```
Testing detect_protocol_by_index
1.5673476169999958
Testing detect_protocol_by_urlparse
15.466406801000176
Testing detect_protocol_by_regex
3.0660895540004276
```

#### Source

```
import sys 
import timeit
import re

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0): 
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
else:
    from urlparse import urlparse


def detect_protocol_by_index(url):
    ind = url.find("://")
    return url[0:ind] if (ind != -1) else 'default_prot'

def detect_protocol_by_urlparse(url):
    scheme = urlparse(url).scheme
    return scheme if scheme else 'default_prot'

regex = re.compile('^[^:]+(?=:\/\/)')
def detect_protocol_by_regex(url):
    match = regex.match(url)
    return match.group(0) if match else 'default_prot'

### TEST SETUP ###

test_urls = ['www.example.com', 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com', 'ftp://example.com']

def run_test(func):
    for url in test_urls:
        func(url)

def run_tests():
    funcs = [detect_protocol_by_index, detect_protocol_by_urlparse, detect_protocol_by_regex]
    for func in funcs:
        print("Testing {}".format(func.__name__))
        print(timeit.timeit('run_test({})'.format(func.__name__), setup="from __main__ import run_test, {}".format(func.__name__)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_tests()
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex for that (`r'^[a-zA-Z]+://'`), and compile it before checking if it is valid or not.

But you have a built-in functions for that:

```
import urlparse
url = urlparse.urlparse('https://www.wwww.com')
print url.scheme
```

Output:

```
>>> https
```

Comment: Built-ins are good but there is no way to get them working in both Python 2 and Python 3 (as I didn't find a way). I'm interested what is better: find() or regex()? Perfomance matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a cross-python version solution:

```
try:
    import urlparse
except ImportError:
    import urllib.parse as urlparse

url = urlparse.urlparse('https://www.example.com')

print(url.scheme)
```

You can add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your script if you want print to be the same thing.

Comment: Noted with thanks. Good way to get things cross-version compatible!